# alpine shell grep regex expression into a list

Tags: shell, grep, sh

i have the following text in a file: `value={VARIABLE_NAME_A}`. And there is probably 20+ of such `VARIABLE_NAME_A, B, C, etc` within the file.

I am trying to use shell script (not bash since its alpine and i didn't install bash) to use `grep` to list out all of these `VARIABLE_NAME_A, B, C` into a variable, and then put them into a list item to iterate over them after that.

However, from my understanding about regex, this format should work.. `"{[A-Z]\w+}"`. But `grep "{[A-Z]\w+}" filename.txt` yields no results..

Not sure what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: There's no such thing as a list in sh; arrays are a ksh extension that bash, zsh, &c later adopted.

Comment: And `\w` is a PCRE extension, not present in either basic or extended POSIX regex syntax. Consider `[[:alnum:]_]+` instead instead. (Also, note that `{` and `}` have other meanings in some regex forms; personally, I'd use `[{]` and `[}]` to disambiguate).

Comment: And plain grep's basic regular expressions needs the quantifier escaped: `[[:alnum:]_]\+`

Comment: I suspect you want `grep -Po "\{[A-Z]\w+\}" file` . `-P` for PCRE, and `-o` to output only the matched strings.

Comment: @stevesliva, if the OP only has Alpine, they may not have GNU grep (IIRC, Alpine ships with busybox instead of GNU tools); and even if they DO have GNU grep, they may not have libpcre (which is an optional compile-time flag to enable), without which they won't have `-P`. It's not safe to assume `grep -P` will be available on any minimal or embedded environment.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use sed instead of grep for portability, e.g. using any POSIX sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*{\([[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]*\)}.*/\1/p' file
```

The above assumes you only have one `{VARIABLE}` per line in your input.

If your sed isn't POSIX compliant in that it doesn't support character classes then this would probably be adequate with any sed, depending on your locale and other content of your input file:

```
sed -n 's/.*{\([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)}.*/\1/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your above post as `file` but adding braces around one or two other instances to test, quoting the metacharacters in your pattern, `grep '{[A-Z]\w\+}' file` returns lines.

If your version supports `-o` *and* `\w\+`,

```
$: grep -o '{[A-Z]\w\+}' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
```

If `-o` but not `\w`,

```
$: grep -o '{[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]\+}' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}

$: grep -o '{[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*}' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}

$: grep -o '{[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]\+}' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}

$: grep -o '{[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*}' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
```

or `awk`, though I'm sure there are better ways than this...

```
$: awk -v ORS='' '/\{[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]+\}/{print gensub(/([^{]*)(\{[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]+\})([^{]*)/, "\\2\n", "g", $0);}' file   {VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}

$: awk -v ORS='' '/\{[A-Z][[:alnum:]_]+\}/{print gensub(/([^{]*)(\{[A-Z][[:alnum:]_]+\})([^{]*)/, "\\2\n", "g", $0);}' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}

$: awk -v ORS='' '/\{[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\}/{print gensub(/([^{]*)(\{[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\})([^{]*)/, "\\2\n", "g", $0);}' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
```

or `perl`, which should also be pretty generally available these days...

```
$: perl -ne 's/[^{]*({[A-Z]\w+})[^{]*/$1\n/g and print' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
```

With `sed`*,

```
$: sed -n 's/.*\({[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]\+}\).*/\1/p' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}

$: sed -n 's/.*\({[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*}\).*/\1/p' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}

$: sed -n 's/.*\({[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]\+}\).*/\1/p' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}

$: sed -n 's/.*\({[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*}\).*/\1/p' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
```

* Note that the `sed` solutions break if there are more than one match on a given line...

```
$: sed -n 's/[^{]*\({[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]\+}\)[^{]*/\1/gp' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
```

A GNU-specific solution would be

```
$: sed -n '/{[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]\+}/{s/[^{]*\({[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]\+}\)[^{]*/\1/g;s/}{/}\n{/g;p}' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
```

If I haven't botched anything, I think this is a more complete solution that will work with any `sed` -

```
$: sed -n '
   s/^[^{]*{/{/
   s/}[^}]*$/}/
   s/}{[^}]*/}\n{/gm
   s/{[^[:upper:]][^}]*}//g
   s/{[[:upper:]][^}]*[^[:alnum:]_}]\+[^}]*}//g
   s/[^{]*\({[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]\+}\)[^{]*/\1/g
   s/}{/}\n{/g
   /{[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]\+}/p
 ' file
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
{VARIABLE_NAME_A}
```