# Running GREP command in windows build system

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, busybox

I am trying to read the text in header file `elf.h` which has following content:-

```
#define ELFOSABIV_STDELF_V1          8U      // STD ELF ABI
#define ELFOSABIV_PRE_STDELF         7U      // latest abi version
#define ELFOSABIV_LATEST             6U      // latest abi version
```

Basically, I am interested in `ELFOSABIV_LATEST` version which is `6U`.

Here is my makefile snippet:-

```
MDCONVERTER := $(HOST_TOOLSBIN)/mdConverter$(EXESUFFIX) --abi-version `$(GREP) -Po '^\#define\s+ELFOSABIV_LATEST\s+\K\S+' $(ELF_DIR)/elf.h`
```

--abi-version parameter to mdConverter.exe has to be `6U`.
**Above makefile snippet works fine in Linux build system where i am getting the output `6U` for grep command. Issue is seen only on windows.**

In windows build system, it uses `busybox_glob.exe` which is software suite that provides several Unix utilities in a single executable. Here is the command in log file :-

```
build/busybox_glob.exe grep -Po '^#define\s+ELFOSABIV_LATEST\s+\K\S+' /home/test/utilities/elf/elf.h
```

Issue i am facing:-

```
BusyBox v1.25.0-FRP-261-gea341c7 (2015-11-01 15:13:33 GMT) multi-call binary.

Usage: grep [-HhnlLoqvsriwFEz] [-m N] [-A/B/C N] PATTERN/-e PATTERN.../-f FILE [FILE]...

Search for PATTERN in FILEs (or stdin)

    -H  Add 'filename:' prefix
    -h  Do not add 'filename:' prefix
 ....
```

Instead of following grep/sed, I am trying to achieve this via perl one liner where the command is same, But output is different as follows:-

In Linux:-

```
perl -ne "print $1 if /#define\s+ELFOSABIV_LATEST\s+(\S+)/" /home/test/elf/elf.h
#define ELFOSABIV_LATEST             6U
```

In Windows:-

```
perl -ne "print $1 if /#define\s+ELFOSABIV_LATEST\s+(\S+)/" /home/test/elf/elf.h
 6U
```

Why is the difference in output among windows and linux above?

Comment: Busybox `grep` doesn't support `-P` or a number of other GNU extensions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77362481/alpine-shell-grep-regex-expression-into-a-list though there might also be one about "why developers hate Windows"

Comment: @tripleee, what could be the best approach to follow? Please advice

Comment: What exactly is "best" depends on your goals. Dropping Windows from your supported platforms will do wonders for your sanity. The duplicate has some technical solutions to your problem; if those work, probably simply accept the duplicate nomination.

Comment: The best advice would probably be to not use `-P`, and thus to use the POSIX flavor of regex instead of the Perl flavor.  I don't see any reason why that would be particularly difficult in this case.

Comment: Or maybe use `sed` instead (though this, too, is primarily a Unix tool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the impetus to use the Perl flavor of regexes (`grep -P`) came from wanting to extract only the ABI version number from the line.  Having started with the questionable choice of `grep -o` for the purpose, you then needed something like Perl's `\K` to separate the version number from the rest of the line.  That relies on features specific to GNU's implementation of `grep`, which you don't have in your Windows build environment, and which you might not have in some other environments, either.

Better in every context would be to use a more appropriate tool for the job in the first place.

#### Option 1

Since you're analyzing macro definitions in a header file, the most fitting choice for the job would be the C preprocessor.  For example, you could include this test file in your distribution:

**elf_version_test.c**

```
#include <elf.h>
ELFOSABIV_LATEST
```

Then, supposing that your makefile defines `CPP` as as a command to run the C preprocessor (for example, as `gcc -E` if you're using gcc), your makefile might do this:

```
MDCONVERTER := $(HOST_TOOLSBIN)/mdConverter$(EXESUFFIX) \
  --abi-version $$($(CPP) -I$(ELF_DIR) elf_version_test.c | tail -n1)
```

#### Option 2

If you're determined to analyze the header directly, then `sed` would be a better choice for that than `grep`.  I would expect any suite that aims to provide a Unix-like build environment to include `sed` in the tools provided, too.  That might look like so:

```
MDCONVERTER := $(HOST_TOOLSBIN)/mdConverter$(EXESUFFIX) \
  --abi-version $$($(SED) -n '/#define ELFOSABIV_LATEST/ s/^.*LATEST[[:space:]]\+\([^[:space:]]\+\).*/\1/p')
```

That's a bit of a mouthful, but it's still a one-liner, and it does the job using only POSIX-specified features.

Comment: I am trying to follow latter approach of yours using `sed`, But it fails with message `sed: unsupported command '`

Comment: I think it's better to use `perl` one liner that works on both windows and linux w.o any dispute in OS specific style. I tried and updated the question. Please check.

Comment: @vam if you want to use the same makefile on Windows that you do on Linux then it's very hard to do it without using a POSIX shell on Windows to execute recipes.  That moots the question of "OS specific style".  And really, there's not much reason to use `make` on Windows *other than* because you want to use a makefile that was built for Linux / Mac / *etc*..